# Motivation behind automorphism bases?

Tags: group-theory, reference-request, model-theory, group-actions

Given a model $\mathcal{M}$ with a domain $M$ and $B \subseteq M$, $B$ is an automorphism base for $\mathcal{M}$ iff $\forall f \in Aut(\mathcal{M}). (\forall b \in B. f(b)=b) \implies f = 1_\mathcal{M}$, that is every automorphism of $\mathcal{M}$ is uniquely determined by its restriction to $B$.

I have seen the interest (particularly in computability on degree structures) in studying the automorphism bases of some model $\mathcal{M}$ when one would like to find out the automorphism group $Aut(\mathcal{M})$. In particular I can understand that knowing small automorphism base for a given model, immediately bounds the size of the automorphism group, i.e. $\# Aut(\mathcal{M}) \le \# \mathcal{M}^{B}$. As one can focus only on the elements of $B$ instead of the whole $M$, many questions, e.g. a rigidity of $\mathcal{M}$ get simplified.

However, I would like to know the relation between the automorphism group of $\mathcal{M}$ and its reduct $\mathcal{B}$ with the domain $B$. I found out that it is not generally true that $Aut(\mathcal{B}) \hookrightarrow Aut(\mathcal{M})$ or $Aut(\mathcal{M}) \hookrightarrow Aut(\mathcal{B})$. However, one could perhaps say something on the generators and the defining relations of the two groups.

I wish I could make my question more precise, but to me right now it seems that there should be more reasons for studying the automorphism bases than the ones I stated. Could we at least say something more if we restrict the model $\mathcal{M}$ to be a partial order $(M,\le)$?

Comment: You can always assume $B$ is a substructure. (It may help the reader to say it explicitly.)

Comment: It is difficult to answer the question in general. It is possible to say something if $\cal M$ is saturated. You could gain insight into your problem by studing the case when $\cal M$ is the contable dense linear order without enpoint or the countable random graph.

Comment: @PrimoPetri Is there anything more one can use the automorphism bases when inspecting the automorphism group of the Turing degrees (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Turing_degree) in particular? Even if you could direct me to too broad or general sources of which you know, I would find that helpful.

Comment: When $M$ is a saturated structure B is an automorphism base if and only if def$(B)=M$.That is if every element of $\cal M$ is 1st−order definable over $B$. But in the case you are interest in (Turing degrees) the structure $\cal M$ is not saturated. So one direction of the equivalence above fails: the notion of base is a weaker than 1st-ordr definability. Turing degrees are one of the widest possible structure and I am afraid that model/group theory can help you very little